# Loading indirect aggregate relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

So when I do this:

`$category->load('posts.comments');`

It works like expected.
But if I try:

`$category->loadMin('post.comments', 'like_count');`

I get error like this:

`Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::post.comments()`

What could be wrong? Is 'load[Min|Max|Avg...]' functions not meant to work with indirect relationships?